# Cannot connect to instance of Tomcat 6 started in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I am running Tomcat 6.0.36.  The server runs fine when run standalone in the console.  I also configured Eclipse to be able to run it so that I can debug.  The configuration went through successfully with no errors.  However, when I ran the server, I was unable to access `http://localhost:8080` in a browser (get a 404).

Here is the Eclipse trace:

```
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: <my path>
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 294 ms
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 164 ms
```

The console trace is as follows:

```
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.23 using APR version 1.4.6.
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1026 ms
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Feb 27, 2013 6:02:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 341 ms
```

The first thing I noticed is the 2nd line from the Eclipse trace:

`INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path`

while the well functioning console trace reports

`INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.23 using APR version 1.4.6.`

Is APR indeed the problem? If yes, how do I fix it so that the Eclipse server uses the same library as the console?

Answer (score 0):

APR is not a problem. When you start tomcat from eclipse, eclipse 'overrides' some server configuration (also you can change config files directly from eclipse in the 'Server' project under package/project explorer).

If you want to access root of your tomcat you can double click on the server (when all projects are removed) and select the configuration that says `Takes control of Tomcat installation`. Then save, restart the server and you'll be able to access `localhost` without any app deployed on it.

P.S. There is a more detailed explanation already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848194/tomcat-works-but-i-cant-reach-http-localhost8080)