# Tomcat 6 Eclipse config -- Server Locations locked for edit

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I am trying to change the default location for my Tomcat server running out of Eclipse EE 1.4.1 so that it uses the original Tomcat installation (which works fine when run standalone out of the console) and not the one created by Eclipse in the workspace as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848194/tomcat-works-but-i-cant-reach-http-localhost8080).  However, my `Server Locations` section on the Tomcat server configuration form is all grayed out (see red rectangle):

[image]

Why is that and how do I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says it all on the page you published :

`Server must be published with no modules present to make changes.`

Stop your server. Undeploy everything and then (the trick part) click on `publish` to be sure to have nothing deployed (ie no files copied to the deploy location, the click on `publish` with no module in your server will erase everything deployed). 
Then you will be able to change the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Before making any changes in **Tomcat Server Location**, you need to remove project(s) deployed on server.

To remove project:
expand tomcat server in "Servers" view
right click and select remove

Answer (score -3):

Just stop your tomcat server first ;)

Comment: This is not sufficient to change the setting.